# Questions on a solution to a problem involving modular arithmetic and prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime greater than $3$ and $n=\frac{2^{2p}-1} {3} $. Prove that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n} $.

---

I have found a solution of this problem on the internet but I'm having trouble understanding it. The solution goes like this:

Notice that $n=\frac {4^p-1}{3}\equiv \frac {4-1}{3}=1\mod p $. So $p\mid n-1$. So we have $2^p\equiv 1\mod n $ and since $p $ is a prime we must have $ord_n (2)=p $ and so $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n $.

Now my doubts are that, how can I conclude that $2^p\equiv 1\mod n $ from the fact $p\mid n-1$? Also, how does $p$ being a prime concludes we must have $ord_n (2)=p $. I don't find the connection there.

Comment: Please provide a link to the solution you found on the Internet.

Comment: @JohnOmielan post number 4 on https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2067568p14778984

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $2^p\equiv1\bmod n$, then ord$_n(2)$ divides $p$, so it's $1$ or $p$, so ...

Comment: Your title is not very informative as to the subject of your question

Comment: @Diff_Equations Note that solution is incorrect. For $2^p \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ means $2^p-1 \ge n$, but $n = (2^p-1)\left(\frac{2^p-1}{3}\right) \gt 2^p-1$ contradicts this. Instead, the AoPS thread [a number theory problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1446504p8266158) stated it's from the British MO $1993$, with a link to [\equiv 1 (mod m)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h487127) which has a relatively brief, correct solution. Note there's also other AoPS threads, e.g., [Division problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1587556p9826566).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner feel free to edit it....I couldn't think about how to describe the problem in the title with the given word limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\frac{4^p - 1}{3}$ is a Fermat pseudoprime with respect to 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243884/frac4p-13-is-a-fermat-pseudoprime-with-respect-to-2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%3D%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B2p%7D-1%7D%7B3%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cequiv%201%5Cpmod%7Bn%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1). There are also several AoPS threads, several of which I've mentioned in my earlier comment.